# useNumberInput hook in Chackra with Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, chakra-ui

the problem is that for some reason, the increment and decrement buttons do not affect the final value in the input, but when you directly enter the value in the input, the value changes.

```
import { Box, Button, FormControl, FormErrorMessage, FormLabel, HStack, Input, useNumberInput } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Field, useField } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';

interface TextInputProps{
    name: string;
    label: string;
}

const CountInput: React.FC<TextInputProps> = ({ name, label}) => {
    const [field, { error, touched }] = useField(name);
    const {
        getInputProps,
        getIncrementButtonProps,
        getDecrementButtonProps,
    } = useNumberInput({
        step: 1,
        defaultValue: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        precision: 0,
    })

    const inc = getIncrementButtonProps();
    const dec = getDecrementButtonProps();
    const input = getInputProps({ ...field });


    return (
        <Field name={name}>
            {({ form }: any) => {
                return (
                    <FormControl isInvalid={form.errors[name] && form.touched[name]}>
                        <FormLabel htmlFor={name}>{label}</FormLabel>
                        {description && <Box mb={5}>{description}</Box>}
                        <HStack maxW="320px">
                            <Button {...dec}>-</Button>
                            <Input id={name} onChange={(val) => form.setFieldValue(field.name, val)} {...input} />
                            <Button {...inc}>+</Button>
                        </HStack>
                        <FormErrorMessage>{form.errors[name]}</FormErrorMessage>
                    </FormControl>
                );
            }}
        </Field>
    );
}

export default CountInput;
```

I am guessing that the problem is with passing the property spread `...field` to `getInputProps()`, which in turn resets the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `onChange` to `useNumberInput` after the `...field` spread as follows:

```ts
const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(name);
const { getInputProps, getIncrementButtonProps, getDecrementButtonProps } =
useNumberInput({
  ...field,
  onChange: (valueAsString, valueAsNumber) => helpers.setValue(valueAsNumber),
});
```

because the `onChange` parameter of `useNumberInput` expects

```ts
(method) UseCounterProps.onChange?(valueAsString: string, valueAsNumber: number): void
```

while the `onChange` of `field` from `useField` has a different signature.

Answer (score 0):

what is the content of field?

I am also trying to use the useNumberInput hook in Chakra, the get input props only accepts some values and here they are

```
export declare function useNumberInput(props?: UseNumberInputProps): {
    value: React.ReactText;
    valueAsNumber: number;
    isFocused: boolean;
    isDisabled: boolean | undefined;
    isReadOnly: boolean | undefined;
    getIncrementButtonProps: PropGetter<any, {}>;
    getDecrementButtonProps: PropGetter<any, {}>;
    getInputProps: PropGetter<any, {}>;
    htmlProps: {
        defaultValue?: string | number | undefined;
        value?: string | number | undefined;
    };
};
```